# Exact Line Search in Projected Gradient Descent

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How is exact line search adapted for projected gradient descent in convex optimization?

One way I think of is that unconstrained exact line search is run, and the new point is projected into the feasibility domain (constraint set).
I am not sure projected gradient descent has a convergence proof in that case. Does it?

Another way can be that the constraints are considered when performing exact line search. Then I am not sure how to solve the exact line search problem.

Comment: Maybe you could get more help at: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I believe this is a math problem, that is why I asked it here.

Comment: Why would you do an exact line search in the first place? If the line search takes you outside of the feasible region, then a lot of the work will be wasted.

Comment: Other options I am aware of are constant step size (which needs tuning and hence not so appropriate), and backtracking line search. If exact line search is not suitable, then backtracking might be a better one?

Comment: Yes, for projected gradient, backtracking is definitely your best bet. Look at the [Wolfe conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions) for good tests for when to stop the backtracking.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.